# PHP Simplexml failing on localhost

Tags: php, localhost, simplexml

I'm editing a mashup of mine where I fetch last.fm data through their API (xml).

For some reason, my localhost can't connect to the file: it gives the following error.

> failed to open stream: A connection
>   attempt failed because the connected
>   party did not properly respond after a
>   period of time, or established
>   connection failed because connected
>   host has failed to respond. in
>   C:\Web\Apache\Apache2\htdocs\soctfm\user.php
>   on line 35

and

> I/O warning : failed to load external
>   entity

The problem, is, is that it works fine on my main server. When I try to fetch the xml from my localhost it fails.

`allow_url_fopen` is on for both servers. So it isn't that. It could be a PHP version error.

Using PHP 5.1.4 on my localhost.

Using PHP 5.2.5 on my main server.

I must add, which I think could be the problem, I'm working from my university internet. This means, we have to connect through a proxy to the internet.

You see, in the end, everything is supposed to work fine. The XML and code works perfectly on my main server, but manages to fail on my localhost, and I don't know why.

Is there any more debugging I can do? Could it be the proxy?

Answer (score 3):

It's almost certainly your proxy server.
If you use [curl](http://php.net/curl) you can set it up to go through your proxy.

Answer (score 3):

If, like you say, you are behind a proxy, your [`simplexml_load_file`](http://php.net/simplexml_load_file) will probably fail : PHP will not be able to connect directly to the remote server, and won't be able to download the XML file.

Two possible solutions :

- first, fetch the data, with something else *(like curl, configureg to use the proxy ; see the options you can use with [`curl_setopt`](http://www.php.net/curl_setopt))* ; and only then, use [`simplexml_load_string`](http://www.php.net/simplexml_load_string).
- Or, use [`stream_context_create`](http://php.net/stream_context_create) to configure a stream that uses the proxy.

  - About that, you can see [my answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1336262/filegetcontents-getaddrinfo-more-specifically-behind-a-proxy/1336419#1336419) : it was the same problem you are experiencing
  - Though, you'll probably have to fetch the XML data first, with `file_get_contents`, and, only then, use `simplexml_load_string` to load it, as `simplexml_load_file` doesn't seem to accept a stream context as parameter :-(

The second solution should work quite nice, I suppose ; and shouldn't require too much work : just a stream context to configure when you are on localhost.

Which means less work than having to deal with curl, I suppose ;-)

Have fun !

Comment: Good answer, although I disagree with your implication that "having to deal with curl" is difficult.