# How to have PHP to use Proxy Setting to connect to internet?

Tags: php, proxy

I'm behind a proxy server that does not allow a direct connection to internet. All of my PHP applications fail to connect to internet for their update checks and etc.

How can I tell PHP my Proxy Settings?

I don't want to enter proxy settings into the code, I want PHP itself use it via a global config setting or something similar.

Answer (score 19):

if almost all of you internet access need a proxy, I'd prefer do like this.

```
//add this as the first line of the entry file may it is the index.php or config.php
stream_context_set_default(['http'=>['proxy'=>'proxy-host:proxy-port']]);
```

the proxy will work for `file_get_contents` but not `curl_exec`

[here is a official document.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-set-default.php)

Comment: sorry for my mistake, the stream api is not affect the curl, if you use curl, you'd better set it by `curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy_url);`, and if you use both, you can add both two.

Comment: I couldn't get it work with a proxy server that has password

Comment: @Tarik if your proxy server need a basic authentication, your need to do it like this `stream_context_set_default(['http'=>['proxy'=>'proxy-host:proxy-port', 'header'=>'Proxy-Authorization: Basic '.base64_encode('your-username:your-password')]]);`

Comment: @Tarik the key point is the `Proxy-Authorization` header, you can find more information at [@pascal-martin 's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1336419/4045767)

Comment: @IanHu Thanks, I found my solution with this code: '$curlProxy = array(
  'http'=>array(
 'method'=>"GET",
 'header'=>"Proxy-Authorization: Basic AUTH_CODE_HERE==\r\n" .
     "Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive",
 'proxy'=>"IP_ADDRESS:PORT"
  )
);'

Answer (score 14):

This depends on how your PHP application connects to the internet.

If taking the most likely situation using PHP cUrl. In that case the following options will help you:

```
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy_url); 
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, "[username]:[password]");
```

See also: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: thanks for the answer. but consider that this may be applied just for my own codes. what about other PHP applications like Drupal? I need PHP itself connect through Proxy not via the code.

Answer (score 6):

Sample code:

```
function getUrl($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init(); 
    $timeout = 5; // set to zero for no timeout 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "http://proxy.example.com"); //your proxy url
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, "8080"); // your proxy port number 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, "username:pass"); //username:pass 
    $file_contents = curl_exec($ch); 
    curl_close($ch); 
    return $file_contents;
}

echo  getUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes it's possible!

You can configure `stream_context_set_default` in a file, and include this file in all your Php program, by using `auto_prepend_file` php.ini property.

I wrote a small gist about:

https://gist.github.com/ebuildy/381f116e9cd18216a69188ce0230708d

And an article in french:

https://medium.com/@thomasdecaux/param%C3%A9trer-par-d%C3%A9faut-un-proxy-pour-php-file-get-content-3e9a32416979#.6zbg605cx

This technique is "cool" because, this allows your sys-admin to configure the host, so developer don't have to change anything in the code.

Comment: The most sensible approach, although probably needs `curl_setopt` too.

Answer (score 2):

I searched over the internet and could not find anything about **stream_context_set_default()** with a ***password protected*** proxy server.

Then I thought that password in basic authorization is sent in headers.
So I modified the headers with the password extracted from a CURL request and it worked perfect!!!

**Here is how you do it:**

First send this request to any domain (example.com) as below:

```
curl -v -U user:pass -x your_proxy_ip:port --url https://example.com
```

See the curl sent headers and I got these proxy lines to use later:

```
>   Trying XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX...
> Connected to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX) port YYYY (#0)
> Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to example.com:443
> Proxy auth using Basic with user 'your_username_here'
> CONNECT example.com:443 HTTP/1.1
> Host: example.com:443
> Proxy-Authorization: Basic YW1hem9uOnXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX25SMg
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established
<
< Proxy replied OK to CONNECT request
```

OK now it is time to build our custom header:

```
$default_opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Proxy-Authorization: Basic YW1hem9uOnXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX25SMg\r\n" .
              "Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive",
    'proxy'=>"XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:YYYY"
  )
);

$default = stream_context_set_default($default_opts);


$result = file_get_contents("https://ipleak.net/json/");
print_r(json_decode($result));
```

And it works perfect, you get the IP of your proxy server in response!

Comment: How do you get this ? YW1hem9uOnXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX25SMg

Comment: so url has usename and password encode in base64 - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Proxy-Authorization

Comment: What are you doing with $default ?

Answer (score 1):

I use the PEAR [HTTP_Request2](http://pear.php.net/package/HTTP_Request2/redirected) module.

Here is a simplified version of my UrlOpen() function:

```
function UrlOpen($url)
{
  $request = new HTTP_Request2($url);

  $request->setConfig(array(
    'proxy_host' => '192.168.1.6',
    'proxy_port' => 8080,
    'proxy_user' => 'MYUSER',
    'proxy_password' => 'MYPASS',
    'ssl_verify_peer' => False,
    'connect_timeout' => 3,
  );

  return $request;
}

$req = UrlOpen($url);
$res = $req->send();
if ($res->getStatus() == '200')
  $data = $request->getBody();
```

Answer (score 0):

For Drupal you can set proxy configuration in your settings.php file.

`$conf['proxy_server']` and so on.

More details [here](http://devincarlson.ca/blog/configuring-drupal-use-proxy-server-when-making-external-http-requests)

Answer (score 0):

For some scripts, all you have to do is set the environment variable `HTTP_PROXY`.  That was the case for both `composer.phar` and media-wiki's maintenance/`update.php` scripts.

E.g.:

```
setenv HTTP_PROXY http://1.2.3.4:3934
```

If your proxy is at 1.2.3.4 listening on port 3934.  Worked for me.