# How to bypass cloudflare bot verification Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LadqF.jpg)The problem is when I open the site through the octolooks parsing plugin. The resource issues protection for checking the bot. How can you bypass it? Can somehow fake Cookies?. sorry for my bad english(

Comment: Do you control that domain in Cloudflare? If so, you might be able to relax the rules. If you don't, then Cloudflare is doing what it is supposed to be doing which is block bots.

Comment: No. I don't control. When I go from the browser, it opens the site without checking. If plagin ( frame ) the addition, then captcha.

Comment: The site's author has enabled bot protection for a reason. Your code, regardless of intention, is a bot. Cloudflare's algorithm for bot protection is proprietary. Your best bet is to try to mimic a real desktop browser, including same headers and even the order that the headers are delivered in. They might also detect the network you are scraping from, so you might need to proxy your connection.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! Do you know how to add vpn for wp to let outgoing traffic through it?

Comment: A VPN would be installed and configured at the OS level. A proxy can be configured at the application (PHP, WordPress, etc.) level, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3892635/231316