# file_get_contents behind a isa proxy under apache

Tags: php, proxy

I am developing a script which deal with accessing remote site data. For this purpose i am using `file_get_contents()` function. it was working fine in home but no connectivity in office.
     then after googling i found using proxy header with `file_get_contents()`

my script is as follow which i got from stackoverflow's thread [file_get_contents()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1336262/file-get-contents-behind-a-proxy)

```
$auth = base64_encode('mywindowlogin:password');

$opts = array('http' => array('proxy' => 'tcp://172.20.10.130:8080', 'request_fulluri'       => true,'header' => "Proxy-Authorization: Basic $auth",));
$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$data = file_get_contents('http://www.lesco.gov.pk/', false, $context);

echo $data;
```

this OUTPUT with an ERROR

```
[function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! 
HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required ( The ISA Server requires
authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web P in 
D:\php\docs\url.php on line 7
```

**Real question** Comes here that in office they are using ISA Proxy server and i am using PHP on apache

1. do i need to use Window login as
   userid or something esle?
2. i am doing something wrong while passing
   userid and password for proxy authorization?  OR
3. What i am doing is not the right way of doing it?

please suggest me how or what to do make `file_get_contents` working through proxy server.
thanks in advance

Comment: i think curl will also have the same problem and will require proxy header for authentication