# How to set the proxy for php in Ubuntu?

Tags: php, proxy

I am on my college network which uses a proxy server with authentication to browse the internet.

I am trying to fetch the data from a web-site using `html_get_contents`, but running the script on the terminal gives me this error:

> `PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(http://www.google.com/): failed to open stream:`
>   `Network is unreachable in /var/www/api/get_contents.php on line 2`

The code I am using to do this is as follows:

```
<?php
    $contents = file_get_contents("http://www.google.com/");
    echo $contents;
?>
```

It seems like I need to set the proxy for `php` to get the contents, where do I set this?

Answer (score 1):

Use [curl](http://php.net/curl).

In http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php set options: "CURLOPT_PROXYAUTH", "CURLOPT_PROXYPORT", "CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE"

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot @AlexeyKa, I wanted to use `file_get_contents` for now and got the answer from the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139459/file-get-contents-behind-a-isa-proxy-under-apache?rq=1