# youtube api json feed php error

Tags: php, api, youtube, json

Okay so what i am trying to achieve is use the youtube api to fetch some feeds. the feeds are json-c encoded. so i tried using file_get_contents method to convert the json feedurl into a string and json decode it. here is the code snippet:

```
$feedURL = "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=surfing&v=2&alt=jsonc";
$json = file_get_contents($feedURL,0,null,null);
$result = json_decode($json, true);
echo $result;
$id = $result->{'data'}->{'items'}[0]->{'id'};
echo "The video id is: ".$id;
```

But i get this stupid error Warning: file_get_contents(https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=surfing&v=2&alt=jsonc) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: Connection refused in /opt/lampp/htdocs/date.php on line 13
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /opt/lampp/htdocs/date.php on line 16
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /opt/lampp/htdocs/date.php on line 16
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /opt/lampp/htdocs/date.php on line 16

The file's name is date.php and i am running it on localhost on a linux machine behind a proxy server.

i think the connection refused thing suggests there might be an ip conflict or something. I don't know. Could somebody please help me fix this?

Comment: Check with another URL and verify that the proxy you are closing the door.

Comment: I already tried that. It gives the same error with any other url howeveer the files on localhost can be accessed withouth any problem using this method

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1336262/file-get-contents-behind-a-proxy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `curl`

```
$feedURL = "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=surfing&v=2&alt=jsonc";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $feedURL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
//curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_PROXY,"x.x.x.x:8888"); // Proxy Use
$json = curl_exec($ch);

$result = json_decode($json, true);
foreach($result['data']['items'] as $items)
{
    var_dump($items['id']);
}
```

Comment: I am sorry but i tried curl. It doesnot give out any errors but it shows nothing. Anyway I figured out the problem, it was a proxy issue indeed. Thanks for all the help guys. I really appreciate it

Comment: just add your proxy `IP` and `port` here `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_PROXY,"x.x.x.x:8888");`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$url = 'http://www';

 $proxy = 'tcp://xxx:8080';

 $context = array(
    'http' => array(
        'proxy' => $proxy,
        'request_fulluri' => True,
        ),
    );

 $context = stream_context_create($context);

 $body = file_get_contents($url, False, $context);
```

```
foreach($result["data"]["items"] as $val) {
  echo $val["id"]."<br/>";
}
```

Comment: my bad! so we need to specify the proxy ip address and port in the $proxy i guess.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the proxy you are closing the connection. There is already an answer to the problem of access through proxy with file_get_contents

[file_get_contents behind a proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1336262/file-get-contents-behind-a-proxy)