# PHP failed to open stream when accessing url through proxy

Tags: php, proxy, xampp

I'm running a php site on localhost and i'm getting the following error.

> Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.engadget.com/rss.xml)
>   [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request
>   failed! in C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\infohut\rss_read_class.php on
>   line 26

but when i run the same hosted in a real server, it doesn't give any error.

Also note that my local pc is connecting through a proxy and when i tried from a different pc with a direct connection to internet, the problem is not there.

So my guess is it has something to do with the proxy.

I'm using xampp for windows installation with php 5.1.4 and Apache 2.2.2

I tried adding my proxy settings to php.ini as well using below

> pfpro.proxyaddress
>
> pfpro.proxyport

still couldn't figure is out. Please advise if i need to change any other settings or anything.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [file_get_contents behind a proxy?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1336262/file-get-contents-behind-a-proxy)

Answer (score 0):

You should enable [allow_url_fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php) in your php.ini

Comment: this is enabled. as i mentioned it doesn't work only when i'm behind a proxy.