# Http response header and body not correct as expected

Tags: php, http

I am working on proxy with PHP. In my php code I am sending proper required headers and expected to get response body and headers. However I am getting response body correctly as I want but not getting headers properly (supposed to get Status 200 but getting 401). When i traced with firefox I found that SAP URL itsself making 2 request internally by using data which I send. so with my first request it is not authenticated so SAP url itslef managining to send same request again and 2nd time it gives both proper response body with headers. Howevber I php code when I get it i get response body from 2nd response and headers from 1st response.
here is code.

```
    $opts = array( 
      'http'=>array( 
             'method'=>"POST", 
         'content' => $xml_request,
             'header'=>array("Host:" . $sap_url,                                                                                                              
           "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8",                                                                     
           $authstring,$xml_request) 
              ) 
     );

    $context  = stream_context_create($opts);   
$result = file_get_contents($sap_url, false, $context); 


$http_res_array =   get_headers($sap_url);
```

Comment: So How should I get response headers from 2nd request ?

Comment: you answer is here - 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1336262/file-get-contents-behind-a-proxy

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use curl functions instead and do BOTH requests yourself. file_get_contents, does the second request for you, but takes away the possibility to fetch the second headers.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little old but anyways:

You're using the `get_headers()`-function to get the headers. It's [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php) states that:

> Fetches all the headers sent by the server in response to a **[new]** HTTP request

It doesn't empathize that this function will actually send a *new* request to the server and return the response-header for *that* request. Therefor, the headers can be slightly different.

Since you're using `file_get_contents()` to load the content, you can use the global [`$http_response_header`-variable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php) *right after* your request, which will contain the response-header from the last executed request.