# .htaccess - Masking and redirecting to a subdirectory on a different server

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dns, masking, subdirectory

I'm looking for some help with my .htaccess file.

In short, I have a bunch of content up in the subdirectory `www.myserver.com/forum/` (this directory is not my choice and cannot be changed), which includes both a forum (`myserver.com/forum/forum`) and a wiki (`myserver.com/forum/wiki`) and this is abviously not an ideal layout. I do not own myserver.com and there is content there that is not mine, though I have full access to the entire server.

I also have a domain name `www.mydomain.com`, which I want to redirect and mask such that if a user goes to `mydomain.com/<something>` they will be shown the content from `myserver.com/forum/<something>` while still being shown `mydomain.com/<something>` in the address bar.

One other thing I'd like to see, although it isn't vital, would by for a 404 generated by someone typing in `mydomain.com/somethingThatDoesNotExist` should redirect to `mydomain.com/404.php` instead of myserver.com's default 404.

I've tried a number of different approaches and searched extensively for the past day or so online - I'm sure that the answer is even here on SO somewhere, but all of the guides/examples I've tried have not worked and I feel like I'm going in circles.

Many thanks in advance.

EDIT: And I do know for sure that .htaceess is enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if a user goes to mydomain.com/ they will be shown the
>   content from myserver.com/forum/ while still being shown
>   mydomain.com/ in the address bar.

First thing you need to understand that this is ONLY possible if `mod_proxy` is enabled on the Apache server of `mydomain.com`.

Once you've enabled mod_proxy, mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` on `mydomain.com`, put this code in its `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://myserver.com/$1 [L,P]
```

I will have to think little more about your 404 requirement, but if you get this working I am sure we can find a workaround for that as well.

Comment: Thankyou for your reply. I was not able to modify htaccess on `mydomain.com` because it is registered with godaddy and they only appear to allow modification through their interface. However, I have managed to set everything up so that typing in `mydomain.com/<something>` will forward to `myserver.com/forum/<something>` correctly, so now I just need htaccess code to make `mydomain.com/<something>` appear in the address bar.

Comment: Ok sure let me know it goes. Just keep in mind that if `P` flag isn't used (with mod_proxy enabled) then external redirection will occur and URL will indeed change in the browser.

Comment: No it should not because it is not presenting a different content for human users and search engines.

Answer (score 0):

You could do some proxying with PHP or whatever other language they allow..

Take a look at [file_get_contents behind a proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1336262/file-get-contents-behind-a-proxy)